# ListBox scroll bar

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I'm using @Html.ListBox and was wondering if there is a why in css to change the color of it, the size of the part you click on to move up and down etc

tried the scrollbar- css but doesn't seem to work.

This is for a c# mbvc5 app.